# Return an NSArray of File URLS for Each File

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I'm looking to return an `NSArray` which contains all of the files `URLS` located within a particular folder in `iOS`.

In this case I'm looking inside the **Ryan/Bob/FolderWithInfo** - which contains 4 files. I want to get the file `URL` of each of these files.

Here is a example of an output I'm looking for :

```
NSArray *array = @[

@"file:///var/mobile/Applications/8D5EBBB2-6726-4FE9-95CB-453635443643/Documents/Ryan/Bob/FolderWithInfo/Layout1.csv",
@"file:///var/mobile/Applications/8D5EBBB2-6726-4FE9-95CB-453635443643/Documents/Ryan/Bob/FolderWithInfo/Layout2.csv",
@"file:///var/mobile/Applications/8D5EBBB2-6726-4FE9-95CB-453635443643/Documents/Ryan/Bob/FolderWithInfo/Layout3.csv",
@"file:///var/mobile/Applications/8D5EBBB2-6726-4FE9-95CB-453635443643/Documents/Ryan/Bob/FolderWithInfo/Layout4.csv",
];
```

How is this achievable?

**Edit**:
I have tried this and thought of maybe prepending the main path after, but there has to be a more efficient way :)

```
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
directory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/%@", directory, @"Ryan, @"Bob", @"FolderWithInfo"];

NSArray *files=[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error];
NSLog(@"mag1 directory: %@",files);
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an NSArray of filenames of all files in a given directory in my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272042/how-do-i-get-an-nsarray-of-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-given-directory-in-my-app)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/907444/2043580

Comment: But note that `NSFileManager` only returns relative file names. So you should use `[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]` in order to get the absolute path.

Comment: @CodeMound You get the filenames, and afterwards you can simply prepend the folderpath.

Comment: @CodeMound the `NSFileManager` methods that return URLs give full URLs. It's the ones that return arrays of `NSString` that return filenames.

Comment: @Ben Did you take any time to look at the docs for `NSFileManager`? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Leandros Thats what i was thinking but there has to be a more efficient way :)

Comment: @Ben Yeah, that's right. It's not the most sophisticated way, though.

Comment: @maddy correct. contentsOfDirectoryAtURL - the method that should be used - returns filenames

Comment: @maddy I've just revised my answer to show what i have tried :)

Comment: @CodeMound That method returns file URLs, not filenames.

Comment: Note that the URLs returned by `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` can have a different base path than the directory you passed in if the directory has symbolic links. To avoid surprises you therefore might want to grab the `lastPathComponent` and append that to the directory URL and use those URLs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, use [`- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)url includingPropertiesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions)mask error:(NSError **)error`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtURL%3aincludingPropertiesForKeys%3aoptions%3aerror%3a).

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/leandros/temp"];
NSArray *urls = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:0 error:&error];
```